# How to separate space separated arguments using argparse in python

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am writing a script in python 3 which takes space separated arguments from command line. Depending on the first argument I call different methods.
When calling the script it looks like this:

```
python name.py [-k] [-p pr] number filename
```

The user will give or [-k] or [-p pr] (not both), number and filename.

 

***for example:*** 

1. `python name.py -k 3 filename`
if the user gives -k then I want to call a function which will have as arguments the number 3(n1) and the input_filename(filename).

```
def function1(n1, filename):
    code
```

2. `python name.py -p 2 3 filename`
if the user gives -r then I want to call a function which will have as arguments the number 2(pr), the number 3(n1) and the input_filename(filename).

```
def function2(pr, n1, filename):
    code
```

How can I separate the arguments from the command line and use them as arguments for the functions (using argparse)?

Comment: Please make an effort, following [the `argparse` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). They're *quite* comprehensive, and what you're doing is fairly simple; only tricky bit is knowing about mutually exclusive groups, which are still clearly documented. If it doesn't work, post a [MCVE] of the problem for us to fix.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have already tried looking there but i will search again. Using sys is super easy but I wanted to try argparse since I have never used it before. I will let you know if I still need help. Thank you

Comment: `sys` is not "easy" for stuff like this; it's really easy to make a mistake, and you have to write and maintain your usage message separately. The `argparse` docs have plenty of examples you can essentially copy and paste, then tweak to match your specific case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ```if argv[1]=="-p":
    function1(int(argv[2]), int(argv[3]), argv[4])
if argv[1]=="-k":
    function2(int(argv[2]), argv[3])``` This way works and I believe it's easier. Could you please indicate which unit should I look into in argparse document?

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse

def function1(n1, filename):
    print('doing 1')
def function2(pr, n1, filename):
    print('doing 2')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-k', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pr')
parser.add_argument('number', type=int)
parser.add_argument('filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

# could use mutually_exclusive_group, but with this simple alternative
# this is just as good.  Tweak as needed.
if args.k:
    function1(args.number, args.filename)
elif args.pr is not None:
    function2(args.pr, args.number, args.filename)
```

add in your comment (corrected):

```
import sys
argv = sys.argv
print(argv)
if argv[1]=="-p": 
    function2(int(argv[2]), int(argv[3]), argv[4]) 
if argv[1]=="-k": 
    function1(int(argv[2]), argv[3])
```

test

```
1700:~/mypy$ python3 stack61218370.py -p 2 3 filename
Namespace(filename='filename', k=False, number=3, pr='2')
doing 2
['stack61218370.py', '-p', '2', '3', 'filename']
doing 2
1702:~/mypy$ python3 stack61218370.py -k 3 filename
Namespace(filename='filename', k=True, number=3, pr=None)
doing 1
['stack61218370.py', '-k', '3', 'filename']
doing 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much @hpaujl, it worked. I also tried the other way you proposed(mutually exclusive group.) Could you please let me know if I have written it correctly (for educational reasons I would like to know both ways) . `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-c', action ='store_true')
group.add_argument('-r', '--radius', type = int)
parser.add_argument('nodes', type = int)
parser.add_argument('filename', type = str)
` The way I call the functions is the same.